# My split function doesnt work, error C2664,

Tags: c++, c++11, c2664

So this is supposed to split string and turn it into list:

```cpp
std::list<std::string> strSplit(std::string::iterator begin, std::string::iterator end, char c) {
    while(std::find(begin, end, c) != end) *std::find(begin, end, c) = '\0';
    return std::list<std::string>(begin, end);
}
```

But compiler throws this error:

```
Error: C2664    
'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string
(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)':
 cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'std::initializer_list<_Elem>'
```

And double click redirects to xmemory0 line: 881

```
...
template<class _Objty,
class... _Types>
static void construct(_Alloc&, _Objty * const _Ptr, _Types&&... _Args)
{   // construct _Objty(_Types...) at _Ptr
::new (const_cast<void *>(static_cast<const volatile void *>(_Ptr)))
    _Objty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
}
...
```

Comment: You can't create an `std::list` from `std::string` in such a way. You need to iterate through the string, find substrings that you are interested in and push them into the list.

Comment: std::list constructor #5 ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list ) takes an iterator range begin and end so that's not the problem.  The problem is that a std::string::iterator iterates through characters in the string so the strSplit function needs to return std::list<char>  But that doesn't solve your problem because you expect that sticking a '\0' into a string makes it into 2 strings - it doesn't and you end up with a string containing a '\0' character.  You actually need to make two separate std::string objects and push them into the list.

Comment: You need something like https://onlinegdb.com/H15RI5gtw

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Why not add an answer with all that text and the code? The one major difference from the existing answers I can see is that it will create a `std::list<std::string>` with an empty string in it if `begin == end` - but perhaps that's exactly what OP wants.

Comment: When I started the code there were no answers.  When I finished there were two.  My answer would be substantially the same so I didn't think there was much point making an answer that was the same as an existing answer, but I didn't want to waste the code so I thought I would share it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the returned iterator you get from `std::find` and actually create a `std::string` from it (and the `begin` iterator). Replacing `c` with `\0` would only make the original string have `\0` in it and so would the one and only string in the resulting `std::list<std::string>` also look like.

On that topic - you should probably use `std::string::const_iterator` for this since you probably shouldn't make changes to the original string.

Example:

```
#include <iterator>

std::list<std::string> strSplit(std::string::const_iterator begin,
                                std::string::const_iterator end, char c) {
    std::list<std::string> retval;
    if(begin == end) return retval; // nothing to do here

    while(true) {
        auto fit = std::find(begin, end, c);
        retval.emplace_back(begin, fit); // creates a string in-place using begin and fit
        if(fit == end) return retval;    // if end was found, return what we got        
        begin = std::next(fit);          // else, go another round
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function has multiple issues. Besides *not compiling*. It tries to mutate the string it's trying to **copy** into a list anyway, which doesn't make sense. It also uses `std::find` multiple times for no reason instead of storing its result and reusing it. Here's my version:

```cpp
std::list<std::string> strSplit(std::string::const_iterator const begin,
                                std::string::const_iterator const end,
                                char const c) {
  std::list<std::string> res;
  if (end != begin) {
    auto it = begin, prev = begin;
    while ((it = std::find(it, end, c)) != end) {
      res.emplace_back(prev, it);
      prev = ++it;
    }
    res.emplace_back(prev, end);
  }

  return res;
}
```